# where to cal api to update the child component props on button click

Tags: reactjs

On Button click, I called API and created instances of child component based on api response length and rendered the child component with default state.

Now I need to call the api again and update the state so that it can be rendered on the child component with the updated data. Can anyone please guide me where should I call this api stuff now to update the child component data?

```
displayBootstrapCard() {
    UniqueId.enableUniqueIds(this);
    if (this.state.displayCard) {
      if (this.state.updateCard) {
        console.log("if");
      } else {
        console.log("else");
        let t = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
          let initialLoad = false;
          t.push(
            <Card
              key={this.nextUniqueId()}
              cardname={this.state.data[i]}
              datacount={this.state.dataCount}
              checkboxlist={this.showData()}
              handleSearchEvent={this.handleSearchEvent}
              handleApplyClick={this.handleApplyClickEvent}
            />
          );
        }
        return t;
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the action you are executing to communicate with your API on the second call?

Answer (score 0):

For a loader you can use -

```
{this.state.loading ? <div>Loading</div> : <card />}
```

For initial API call use componentDidMount lifecycle method
like-

```
fetchData() {
  this.setState({loading: true});

  fetch('apiUrl').then(data => {
    this.setState({
       data,
       loading: false
    );
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

and for API call on button click use -

```
<button onClick={() =>  this.fetchData()}>Fetch Data</button>
```

when state changes the component render method is called which have your child component and the child component props will be updated

Comment: See, initially I am showing the loading icon on the cards and at the same time I need to call api to fetch the data and display it in place of loading icon once it fetched.